# HAProxy health check

Tags: linux, load-balancing, haproxy

I have three small questions that relate to the same topic:

1. With HAProxy, is there any way to load balance based on the *current load* of the different servers (ie. routing a request to the least loaded server).
2. If not, why isn't this behaviour built into HAProxy? Are there any *major* performance impacts of doing this? I imagine rather than for example, the instead of looking for the least connections (`leastconn` algorithm), that I'd be looking for the lowest load.
3. If there are no major performance impacts of doing this, is my assumption that one could build this functionality into a custom HAProxy distribution without affecting performance correct?

Answer (score 6):

The only way to do this with haproxy is create a script that haproxy's health check checks. In the script you are checking the load average and if it's a valid load.. return a response code of 200. If it is too high return a 404 or 500 error. Your haproxy  check would look something like

```
option httpchk HEAD /health_check.php HTTP/1.0
```

if haproxy sees any 2xx/3xx response it will be valid.. anything else it will take that node offline till the node's load goes down and the health_check.php scripts returns a 200